# How to find common items in two Laravel collection objects

Tags: php, laravel, collections, set-intersection

I'm trying to compare 2 collections, and put all values present in both into another collection.

So given these collections:

```php
$text1 = collect('burger', 'cheese', 'bread', 'ham');
$text2 = collect('cheese', 'bread', 'tomato');
```

I would like to extract 'cheese' and 'bread'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case you need [intersect](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-intersect) method:

The intersect method removes any values from the original collection that are not present in the given array or collection. The resulting collection will preserve the original collection's keys:

```
$text1Collection = collect('burger', 'cheese', 'bread', 'ham');
$text2Collection = collect('cheese', 'bread', 'tomato');

$resultCollection =$text1Collection->intersect($text2Collection);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`intersect`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-intersect) method available on [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections):

```
$intersect = $text1->intersect($text2);

$intersect->all(); // [1 => 'cheese', 2 => 'bread']
```